# Updating a many-to-many relation with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I'm struggling a bit with a many-to-many relation update using Entity Framework. My tables looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Agreement
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Agreement] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID),
);

CREATE TABLE Price
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),  
    ProductPrice decimal(18,5),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Price] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID),
);

CREATE TABLE AgreementPriceLine
(
    AgreementID int NOT NULL,   
    PriceID int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AgreementPriceLine] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (AgreementID, PriceID), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AgreementPriceLine_Agreement]
    FOREIGN KEY (AgreementID) REFERENCES Agreement (ID)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AgreementPriceLine_PriceID]
    FOREIGN KEY (PriceID) REFERENCES Price (ID) 
);
```

Which Entity Framework mapped like so (using generate model from database, the .edmx file):

```
public partial class Agreement
{
    public Agreement()
    {
        this.Prices = new HashSet<Price>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}

public partial class Price
{
    public Price()
    {
        this.Agreements = new HashSet<Agreement>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Agreement> Agreements { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if I want to update two prices on an agreement, how would I go about that? I tried the following:

```
    public void UpdateAgreementPriceLines(List<Price> prices, Agreement agreement)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
            {
                if (agreement != null)
                {
                    // Make sure the number of prices are equal before attempting to "update" anything
                    if(agreement.Prices.Count == prices.Count)
                    { 
                        // Clear old prices
                        agreement.Prices.Clear();

                        // Add new prices
                        foreach (var price in prices)
                        {                                
                            agreement.Prices.Add(price);
                        }

                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logging.Instance.Fatal(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But it's rather 'hacky' to first empty the collection and then add the new prices. Also, I can't get it to work, the prices are not removed/added at all (and no exception is caught)

Any help/hint on this is greatly appreciated :-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the items from the colletion, like this:

```
agreement.Prices.Remove(priceItem);
```

To remove all objects you can do the following:

```
var prices = agreement.Prices.ToList();
agreement.Prices.RemoveRange(prices);
```

If you don't want to load all items to the memory before the removal method, you can do the following:

```
//supposing that you want to deleted the Price which id = 10

Price deletedPrice = new Price { PriceId = 10 };  
Context.Entry(deletedPrice).State = EntityState.Deleted;  
Context.SaveChanges();
```